# TouchSwipe return distanceX

Tags: jquery, touch, swipe

I using TouchSwipe (http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/). My problem is the distance in swipeStatus event callback is distance between two points (start drag point and current drag point). I only want get x distance or y distance separately only. How do that?

```
swipeStatus: function(event, phase, direction, distance)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the x and y coordinate from the event argument. For swiping, that is:

```
event.pageX
event.pageY
```

Happy coding!

Comment: For some reason when I log event.pageX it always returns 0. Any ideas?